# how to use $val to get value from map in helm for kubernetes?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I got a map in values.yaml:

```
Schedule:
  app1: node01
  app2: node07
  app3: node13
```

and I want to use it in template/app.yaml:

```
{{- $tuplei := untilStep 1 4 1 -}}
{{- range $keyi, $vali := $tuplei }}
---
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      nodeName: {{ $.Values.Schedule.node$vali }}
```

It can't work:

> Error: parse error at (xxx/templates/app.yaml:51): bad character U+0024 '$'
> helm.go:94: [debug] parse error at (xxx/templates/app.yaml:51): bad character U+0024 '$'

I have tried some ways, but still can't make it.

```
#{{- $ScheduleName :=  printf "app%d" $vali }}
#nodeName: get $.Values.Schedule "$ScheduleName"
#can't work, too.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Go `text/template` language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) includes an `index` function, which does an arbitrary lookup by key or index.  So your last form is almost correct: you need to construct the key in a string, and then use `index` to retrieve it.

```yaml
{{- $scheduleName := printf "app%d" $vali -}}
nodeName: {{ index $.Values.Schedule $scheduleName }}
```

Make sure to not quote the `$scheduleName` variable reference, lest the template language interpret it as a string literal.